Docker container hostname resolving not working in .net
I have docker file that runs dotnet test before publishing. Some of the tests are integration tests that require a real database. For that i start a sql server docker container before docker build. I created a custom docker network for the both of them to work on and when i telnet or ping from the container that is building my container to my sql server container that works perfectly, using both the sql server container name and it's ip address. But using the same hostname in the connectionstring of my .net 8 ef core app it throws an exception. Using the ip address of my sql server container which i get from docker network inspection it works just fine. So somehow .net 8 is not able to resolve the sql server container name to it's ip address. Btw calling Dns.GetHostAddresses from the .net app results in a similar exception.
The exception:
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : Name or service not known

An image build can never connect to another container.  You shouldn't need to run integration tests as part of the process of building a reproducible container image; I might run these targeting the built image, as validation after the image is built.

To add on to David's suggestion... you can see this sample doc which demonstrates defining a separate test stage in your Dockerfile and defining an ENTRYPOINT for it: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/tree/main/samples/complexapp#running-tests-as-an-opt-in-stage. That allows you to execute your tests using docker run rather than docker build.

Please include the [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're having.  We can't help you debug code we cannot see.
